# local wordpress on apache2 error 403

Tags: wordpress, apache2, local

I wanna run wordpress on OpenSuse in my local network. 
My virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2:99>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/wordnews/
 ServerName local.wordnews.pl
 ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2.err"
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
 <Directory /var/www/wordnews>
         Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                 AllowOverride AuthConfig Indexes
         Order allow,deny
         Deny from all
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

and add  to /etc/hosts :

```
192.168.0.2 local.wordnews.pl
```

but when i try open this address on broweser, i see:
**Error 403**
and when i try local.wordnews.pl/wp-admin/install.php i see:
**Error 404**

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `Directory` block, you want to make it `Allow` instead of `Deny`

```
<Directory /var/www/wordnews>
     Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
             AllowOverride AuthConfig Indexes
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: true, but still 403 :-/ maybe something is wrong here:
#ls -l
drwxrwxrwx   5 wwwrun      www         4096 Jul 30 09:47 wordnews
all files have same own and permissions

Comment: If you have `Deny from all`, anyone accessing anything in that directory will get a 403 Forbidden